# Rails VALIDATES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
  validates :fname, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2 }
```

How do I add a message to that? Right now the errors says "Fname is too short (minimum is 2 characters)" I'd like it to say First Name and not Fname.

thanks?

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?

```
validates :fname, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2 },
:format => {
:message => 'your message.'}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. error'd: "Either :with or :without must be supplied (but not both)"

Comment: perhaps:
validates :fname, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2 },
:message => 'your message.'

I initially used it with :with but I believe it's possible without

Answer (score 0):

Solution ended up being:

Change the name of the field in your locale file:

```
en: 
  activerecord: 
    attributes: 
      user: 
        fname: First name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
validates :fname, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2 }, :message => "your message goes here"
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to put a friendly column name use code like [this](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/12/change-displayed-column-name-in-rails-validation-messages):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :email => "E-mail address"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

Other way to solve this problem is to take the approach described in this blog post: http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/4/23/better-messages-for-activerecord-validation-errors

Comment: He doesn't want to use "fname" in the error message though. This won't work.

Comment: @Alex thanks for catching that. You're right... Is there a way in Rails to say what the "friendly name" is for a field per model? that might be nice?

Comment: @Alex the first question was "How do I add a message to that?" and yes it does not solve the entire problem. I just updated the answer so that includes resolution to the second problem.